# Non exportable references in future_map

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future

I am experimenting for the first time with the `furrr` package, especially with the `future_map` group of functions.

I'm having trouble understanding how to avoid running into the problem of non-exportable references even with extremely basic functions. Here is a toy example:

```
my_sum = function(x, a){
    return(x+a)
}
options(future.globals.onReference = "error")

library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess)
test = future_map(.x= 1:10, .f = my_sum, a = 1)
```

While the function does run if I don't set the error option, there is clearly some issue in the background, as the error reads `Detected a non-exportable reference (‘externalptr’) in one of the globals (<unknown>) used in the future expression`. I really don't understand how to get around this, any help?

Additional info: running Windows. R is version 4.0.2, furrr is version 0.1.0, future is version 1.19.1

Comment: are you working on Windows?

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem.. without `options(...)` the code runs fine... What is exactly that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I am working on Windows. This error leads me to a series of errors in more complicated functions. What I'm trying to do is understand the functioning of (non) exportable references that lie beneath parallel programming.

Comment: Then I believe you should share a reproducible example of the series of errors you get later, since that is your actual goal.

Comment: Could you provide some session info, e.g. the version of {furrr} and {future}.

Comment: Added additional info

Comment: looks like the problem is related to `future_map`. If you would use: `library(parallel);test <- parLapply(makeCluster(detectCores()), X = 1:10, fun = my_sum, a = 1)`, you have no problem.. it may be necessary to open an issue on `furrr`..?

Comment: I can replicate this with `plan(multisession)`, which is what you get on Windows when using `plan(multprocess)`.

Comment: My suggestion is to only use `options(future.globals.onReference = "error")` for troubleshooting.  You can also use `options(future.globals.onReference = "warning")`.  The default is `"ignore"` because there are lots of false positives.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers. I was basing my question on the assumption that I misunderstood the functioning of multiprocess/multisession. I'll probably use another function that does the same thing and/or open an issue on `furrr`.

Comment: @HenrikB, I was expecting NOT to have the same issue with `future.apply`: `future_lapply(1:10, my_sum, a = 1)`. But I do. Then it is not a problem related to `furrr`, is it? What's the problem here?

Comment: Henrik opened the issue for you: https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues/168. However, since `future.apply` has the same issue, it may be related to `future`.

Comment: Thanks for checking with **future.apply**.  As I write in <https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues/168#issuecomment-706320565>, this is an interesting problem but it's not-critical.  Scanning for non-exportable globals is a complicated problem and `options(future.globals.onReference = "error")` is at best only a clue.